# How to let someone preview a draft?

Tags: user-roles

How can I let a user see my draft post; but don't allow them to edit them?

Some context: I'm the only author and admin on my blog. I would like to let someone else read a post before publishing it.

None of the [builtin roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) seems to be a match for this. The [role scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin seems a bit too complicated at first sight.

What's the easiest way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Share a draft](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shareadraft/) looks like an easy plugin to do this.

(Answering my own question after trying a few different things, other suggestions are still welcome.)

Comment: I'd also recommend [Public Post Preview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/public-post-preview/).

Comment: Just adding this comment to keep this post updated, (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-draftsforfriends) WP Drafts for Friends works very well and has been updated more recently than Share a draft.